# Missing requirement: org.eclipse.mylyn.commons.notifications.feed requires 'osgi.bundle; javax.xml.bind 2.2.0' but it could not be found

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, java-11, javax.xml

[ERROR]   Missing requirement: org.eclipse.mylyn.commons.notifications.feed 1.17.2.v20200813-0821 requires 'osgi.bundle; javax.xml.bind 2.2.0' but it could not be found

I can see this javax.xml.bind jar is available in p2 repo.

still this is asking for this jar, not able to find it.

I am upgrading eclipse 4.23 with java 11.

Comment: Upgrading Mylyn to the latest version via the update site [`https://download.eclipse.org/mylyn/releases/latest/`](https://download.eclipse.org/mylyn/releases/latest/) should solve your issue ([Mylyn 3.26 has been released two days ago](https://www.eclipse.org/lists/mylyn-dev/msg02602.html)).

Comment: I am using eclipse composite and orbit repos. could you help me how I can add this update on the same?

Comment: The mentioned update site is a p2 repository. Please show your target definition file.

Comment: Hello @howlger, 

I build my p2 repo using this p2 repo - 

https://download.eclipse.org/releases/2022-03/

Comment: For Mylyn you have to use `https://download.eclipse.org/mylyn/releases/latest/` in addition. `https://download.eclipse.org/releases/2022-03/` is a year and four releases behind. The staging p2 repo for the upcoming 2023-06 already contains Mylyn 3.26: `https://download.eclipse.org/staging/2023-06/`.

Comment: I download mylyn 3.26.0  and used as additional p2 repo , from this location-  https://download.eclipse.org/mylyn/updates/milestone/S202305081049/index.html

that's resolved my issue. 

Thanks lot for your support @howlger. I really appreciate your help.